# convert a key value pair into 2 different objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Let me explain here**

```
let obj = {manager:XYZ}
//output:[{position:"manager",name:"XYZ"}]
```

*you can also use lodash to find the solution*

Comment: have you tried anything from your end first?

Comment: You don't need loadash vanilla JS is enough, hint use `Object.entries` and `map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use a for-loop:

```js
let obj = {manager:'XYZ'}

let output = [];
for (var key in obj) {
  output.push({ position: key, name: obj[key] });
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries()` to get each key/value pair from the object, and `map()` to iterate over each key:

```js
let obj = {manager:'XYZ'}

let arr = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => ({position: key, name: val}))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `Object.entries`, `map` and some destructuring you can come to a simple solution:

```js
let obj = { manager: "XYZ" };

console.log(
  Object.entries(obj).map(([position, name]) => ({ position, name }))
);
```